# java executor framework's invokeAll equivalent method in spring executor

Tags: spring, multithreading, executor

In java executor framework  to wait until completion of all tasks we have `invokeAll`() method .But while using spring's `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` we have only submit method which returns Future object.So here after completion of first task it is going to be started next task.So If I want to wait until all tasks completed is there any way to do it? means is there any method available in spring which is equal to `invokeAll()` Please correct me if my understanding is wrong..

Comment: maybe not, i have checked all classes include invokeAll() method, but they all point to java.util.concurrent package classes.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap your TaskExecutor with org.springframework.core.task.support.ExecutorServiceAdapter:

```
ExecutorServiceAdapter adapter = new ExecutorServiceAdapter(taskExecutor);

List<Future<V>> futures = adapter.invokeAll(tasks);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In your opinion, this question return back to java but not spring, here i think you should think more on the relation between `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and `ExecutorServiceAdapter`.

Comment: @Crabime ExecutorServiceAdapter is related to spring framework ?

Answer (score 1):

Always fail into `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` source code made me stupid. you remind me the whether `ExecutorServiceAdapter` belongs to spring. Now i think yes, and here is my code to answer your question, hope not wrong.

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPool = atx.getBean("threadPool", ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.class);
    ExecutorServiceAdapter adapter = new ExecutorServiceAdapter(threadPool);
    List<Callable<Integer>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    Callable<Integer> task = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        task = new Callable<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call() throws Exception {
                int time = new Random().nextInt(1000);
                Thread.sleep(100);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has slept " + time);
                return time;
            }
        };
        //submit task and wait to execute
        threadPool.submit(task);
        //add all task to list
        tasks.add(task);
    }

    //get the start time of all threads
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        List<Future<Integer>> result = adapter.invokeAll(tasks);
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(result.get(i).get());
        }
    } catch (ExecutionException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Total time is " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way

```
taskExecutor.getThreadPoolExecutor().invokeAll(callables);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve the same results without using the alternate method is using the submit in for loop.

This approach helped me achieve what I was trying to do. Hope this helps.

```
List<Future<String>> list = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
    Callable<String> callable = new MyTask();

    for(int i=0; i< 5; i++){
        //submit Callable tasks to be executed by thread pool
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(callable);
        //add Future to the list, we can get return value using Future
        list.add(future);
    }

    for(Future<String> future : list){
        try {
            //Here future.get() will wait for task to be completed.
            //Hence small delay will come.
            System.out.println(future.get());
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
```